# QKeyEvent::text() doesn't return accent letter on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qkeyevent

Does anyone know why `QKeyEvent::text()` for typing **` + a** returns one **empty string** and one letter **a** instead of **one empty** string and **à** on Linux? Under Windows this seems to be working fine (same application running under Windows and Linux).

I'm handling the pressed keys via this [class](https://github.com/ksnip/kImageAnnotator/blob/master/src/annotations/items/helper/KeyInputHelper.cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the `Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled` attribute in addition to override the `inputMethodEvent` method:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr): QWidget(parent){
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, true);
    }
protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
        qDebug() << "keyPressEvent" << event->text();
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
    void inputMethodEvent(QInputMethodEvent *event){
        qDebug() << "inputMethodEvent" << event->commitString();
        QWidget::inputMethodEvent(event);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I'm not using a Widget for text input but a Class that Inherits from QGraphicsItem. Setting Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled gives a console entry saying Attribute not supported. I have overwritten the method that you mentioned but it}s not getting called.

Comment: I think I got it, it should be `setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemAcceptsInputMethod, true);`
It looks like the method gives me the correct text now. Need to double check.

Comment: Yes, working now. The keyPressEvent is triggered for the usual Latin letters, when an composite letter occurs, the InputMethod is triggered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, this also Fixes Chinese Character Input, which was not working before in my case and seems to be working now.